# No execution for functions with scanf

Tags: c

```
void reg() {
    char name[60];
    char city[1000];
    puts("Name");
    scanf("%s", name);
    puts("City?");
    scanf("%s", city);
    FILE *fptr = fopen("./src/details.txt", "a");
    fputs(strncat(strncat(name, " ", 61), city, 1061), fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

When I call this function (present in another file) from main, it doesn't execute (program runs without any output). In fact, any function with scanf in my file doesn't execute. However, functions without scanf work fine. Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)

Comment: Try adding `scanf("\n")` at the beginning.

Comment: @AmalK Doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by "*without any output*" ? are *"Name"* and *"City?" print ?

Comment: No, @bruno.....

Comment: are you sure you call *reg* ? did you executed into a debugger ?

Comment: Yes @bruno. I called reg. Also, if I place scanf in working functions, I face the same problem.

Comment: do you redirect stdin/stdout ? do you fork the program ?

Comment: No @bruno........

Comment: what is your OS (windows, a Linux ...) ?

Comment: Windows @bruno...

Comment: (sad ^^) do you run under a tool ? do you have the same behavior when you start your program 'by hand' in a terminal ?

Comment: Post input used.  Better yet: a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for a user input after printing the text, you must use `fflush(stdout)` to clear buffer.

Rather than:

```
puts("Name");
scanf("%s", name);
```

Do:

```
puts("Name");
fflush(stdout); // this
scanf("%s", name);
```

Comment: `puts` flush the output thanks to the newline produced at the end

Comment: `name` is a char array and hence it already refers to the base address of the array so the ampersand is not needed.

Comment: @AmalK is right, remove the `&` and change the comment to be `// don't forget to NOT put an ampersand here` ^^

Comment: if something must be done this is to add the max length to read, and to test the return value, so `if (scanf("%59s", name) != 1) { ...error...}`

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `scanf()` with `fgets()` to read strings.

```
fgets(name, 60, stdin);
```

Also your error with `scanf()` most probably seems to be caused by a trailing whitespace that is left unconsumed.
Add:

```
scanf(" %*c");
```

Or add a call to `getchar()` before calling `scanf()`